# How to implement Category - Subcategory in laravel 5.2 using single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, categories

I'm a newbie in laravel and want to implement category, subcategory in laravel 5, using one table and infinitely deep, attaching the screenshot for your reference.
[One table for category/subcategory that should be infinitely deep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3vFY.png)

Comment: Let research on "recursive menu"

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it **belongsToMany**  relation and have db structure in following way

[image]

Comment: Why db structure in this way ? I want to do it in just 1 table